# Flask Bad Request without any message

Tags: flask

this is so annoying, i got flask Bad Request error without any message, i was try to debug it with `FLASK_ENV=development` and `logger.DEBUG` but nothing shown, just Bad Request message on browser, how do i trace this kind of error ? thankyou

Comment: Going through the exercise of trying to produce a small code sample that demonstrates the problem is a good practice. You might find the problem along the way. If not, it gives you something focused to post here.

Comment: as mentioned by @DaveW.Smith, adding code samples will help us help you identify and fix the issue you are facing. Generally, a bad request(`400`) means you are sending the wrong data body to your server. Make sure you check for all the body parameters sent to the server.